# Why does a Django HttpRequest (POST) appear to set request.data to the value of the "data" key from request.body?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, http-post, wsgi

**Background**

I have a Django wsgi application which also makes use of django-rest-framework. A POST request is made to my application which has a JSON payload containing the key "data", eg.

```
{'meta': {'some': 'stuff'}, 'data': {'other': 'stuff'}}
```

I have noticed that the WSGIRequest object (as soon as it gets initialized, ie. not a django-rest-framework request object yet) has request.body containing the full payload, but request.data containing the value of request.body['data']. My application has been written to depend on the fact that only the "data" key value is present in request.data.

I recently upgraded Django from 1.6 to 1.11 and django-rest-framework from 2.3.8 to 3.8.2. The newer version of DRF implements its own request.data whereas before it was just proxying it to the underlying Django request object. The new implementation sets request.data to the parsed request.body. This breaks my application further down the line.

**Question**

I can't find any indication in the source code or elsewhere that request.data should be different from request.body. To the contrary, several questions seem to take it for granted that they are the same. Can anyone help me in figuring out if I have found a bug or if this is expected behaviour? Is my application making unwarranted assumptions?

Thanks

**Update**

Here is an example postman request:

```
POST /api/data/ProvisioningWorkflow/5aeaf9caa9d1cb000887184f/execute/?hierarchy=1c0ffee2c0deab00da595101&amp;nowait=true&amp;format=json HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json
Authorization: Basic c3lzYWRtaW46c3lzYWRtaW4=
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 5140e8db-6ffa-e2d2-9791-698030fe6caf

{"data":{"name":"_test","parameters":{"parallel":"false","max_workers":"1"},"rollback_disabled":false,"workflow":[{"method":"add","entity_type":"model","entity":"data/Countries","templates":[{"template":"_test"}],"advanced_find_search_direction":"full_tree"}]},"request_meta":{},"meta":{"references":{"form_href":"/api/data/ProvisioningWorkflow/5aeaf9caa9d1cb000887184f/?hierarchy=1c0ffee2c0deab00da595101"}}}
```

If I debug in my wsgi.py, the issue is seen:

```
>>> request.body                                                                                                                              
'{"data":{"name":"_test","parameters":{"parallel":"false","max_workers":"1"},"rollback_disabled":false,"workflow":[{"method":"add","entity_ty 
pe":"model","entity":"data/Countries","templates":[{"template":"_test"}],"advanced_find_search_direction":"full_tree"}]},"request_meta":{},"m 
eta":{"references":{"form_href":"/api/data/ProvisioningWorkflow/5aeaf9caa9d1cb000887184f/?hierarchy=1c0ffee2c0deab00da595101"}}}'             
>>> request.data                                                                                                                              
{u'rollback_disabled': False, u'name': u'_test', u'parameters': {u'max_workers': u'1', u'parallel': u'false'}, u'workflow': [{u'templates':   
[{u'template': u'_test'}], u'entity': u'data/Countries', u'method': u'add', u'advanced_find_search_direction': u'full_tree', u'entity_type':  
u'model'}]}
```

I can see the underlying request object and the behaviour is clear again here:

```
>>> request._request.data                                                                                                                     
{u'rollback_disabled': False, u'name': u'_test', u'parameters': {u'max_workers': u'1', u'parallel': u'false'}, u'workflow': [{u'templates':   
[{u'template': u'_test'}], u'entity': u'data/Countries', u'method': u'add', u'advanced_find_search_direction': u'full_tree', u'entity_type':  
u'model'}]}                                                                                                                                   
>>> request.data                                                                                                                              
{u'request_meta': {}, u'meta': {u'references': {u'form_href':                                                                                 
u'/api/data/ProvisioningWorkflow/5aeaf9caa9d1cb000887184f/?hierarchy=1c0ffee2c0deab00da595101'}}, u'data': {u'rollback_disabled': False,      
u'name': u'_test', u'parameters': {u'max_workers': u'1', u'parallel': u'false'}, u'workflow': [{u'templates': [{u'template': u'_test'}],      
u'entity': u'data/Countries', u'method': u'add', u'advanced_find_search_direction': u'full_tree', u'entity_type': u'model'}]}}                
>>> request.body                                                                                                                              
'{"data":{"name":"_test","parameters":{"parallel":"false","max_workers":"1"},"rollback_disabled":false,"workflow":[{"method":"add","entity_ty 
pe":"model","entity":"data/Countries","templates":[{"template":"_test"}],"advanced_find_search_direction":"full_tree"}]},"request_meta":{},"m 
eta":{"references":{"form_href":"/api/data/ProvisioningWorkflow/5aeaf9caa9d1cb000887184f/?hierarchy=1c0ffee2c0deab00da595101"}}}'             
>>> request._request.body                                                                                                                     
'{"data":{"name":"_test","parameters":{"parallel":"false","max_workers":"1"},"rollback_disabled":false,"workflow":[{"method":"add","entity_ty 
pe":"model","entity":"data/Countries","templates":[{"template":"_test"}],"advanced_find_search_direction":"full_tree"}]},"request_meta":{},"m 
eta":{"references":{"form_href":"/api/data/ProvisioningWorkflow/5aeaf9caa9d1cb000887184f/?hierarchy=1c0ffee2c0deab00da595101"}}}'
```

Comment: I have tried a POST request with a body like your question and I still get full request body. I used djangorestframework==3.3.3 and Django==1.11.3. Could you send the postman of your request, i will test your request with my application.

Comment: Isn't request.POST still accessible inside DRF? Or are you interested in the parsed data?
Also I believe the DRF `Request` object retains the `WSGIRequest` under `_request`, so you could still do `request._request.POST` if absolutely needed; this definitely feels hacky though.

Comment: I will get the postman today. I realise there are ways of getting the data as I want it, however, I am upgrading packages for an extremely large and complex application and if possible I would like to find a way to make request.data behave as before rather then trying to fix every place where it is used.

Comment: Updated the original question. You can see request.data is the parsed request.body, but only the value of the "data" key is present. I thought maybe Django was somehow being clever and allowing attribute access to the keys of the payload, but I couldn't find any evidence for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have answered my own question. I found a piece of middleware that was setting request.data to request.body['data']. The new version of DRF has a namespace conflict here as it also sets request.data, but this happens after the Django middleware takes effect. I overrode initialize_request and manually set _full_data after accessing the data property in order to get around this. Unfortunately it is not practical to change every case where my application uses request.data.